# print blank space in Excel for Null field in MongoDB using PhP

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a Mongo DB with a collection which has two fields `first_name` and `last_name` for 4 of the entries and three fields (two same as above) and "gender" for the other 3 entries.

Now my aim is to create a button and whenever we click it an excel file is downloaded. I have used phpSpreadsheet for this and MongoDB/MongoDB for the database connection.

The problem raises when I try to iterate through the columns and the rows of the database to save the data in an excel file. Obviously, it is because of the `gender` field which is not set in the rest of the entries.

I would like to know if there is any way I can save the NULL  entries with a blank space in the excel file without changing the database itself.

Here is my `Model/user_model.php`

```
    <?php
    class User_model extends CI_Controller{
          public function start_conn(){
                /*Code for mongo connection...*/
                /*Assuming we just want to echo the data rather than saving in excel*/
                $cursor = $database->find();
                return $cursor;
          }
    } 
    ?>
```

Here is my `Controller/user.php`

```
    <?php
    class User extends CI_Controller{
          public function index(){
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $data['result'] = $this->user_model->start_con();

                $this->load->view('user_view', $data);
          }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is my `View/user_view.php`

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>
             database
         </title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php
            foreach($result as $object){
               echo $object->first_name." ".$object->last_name." ".$object->gender."<br>";
            }
         ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Where should I check for empty field and if it's empty how should I print a white space in its place ?

Comment: is your $result contains the gender variable or not? show your $result data

Comment: Hie Pradeep. I have added the code. Although it wasn't written here, I have updated it though. The error message that it throws is 
                   "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\mongo\application\views\user_view.php on line 15"
                   Message: syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: pls make sure $result is an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understand your requirement,
*Your view code should be like this ;*

**Note** : *make sure $result is an array of objects*

```
<?php
   foreach($result as $object)
   {
      /*check gender here if and set to blank('') if has not a value*/
      $gender =  ! empty($object->gender) ? $object->gender : '';

      echo $object->first_name." ".$object->last_name." ".$gender."<br>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: can we do this dynamically? Suppose I don't want to write down a specific field to check if it has any NULL entry. Is there any way to generalize the query entry so that any field from any row which is empty gets printed with a blank space?

Comment: yes you can do it with mysql's control function like `if`.`ifnull` for example `IF(gender IS NULL, '', gender) gender,`